# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'initial_data' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python

i'm creating a tool, and in that tool, it gets some data from an API that it firsts stores on a json. and then I use a py function to store the values on a tuple, but when I try to access it, I get this error. It's a tool for discord to fetch information from a videogame, hosted on my machine

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/pufferpanel/servers/bd502203/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 862, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/lib/pufferpanel/servers/bd502203/scoreposter.py", line 251, in scoreposter
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"```{scorepost(osu_user,mode , False)}```", ephemeral=False)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/lib/pufferpanel/servers/bd502203/scoreposter.py", line 168, in scorepost
    beatmap_id, rank, score_max, n300, n100, n50, nmiss, perfect, int_mods, score_id = extract_initial_data(initial_data)
                                                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'initial_data' where it is not associated with a value

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/pufferpanel/servers/bd502203/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1242, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/var/lib/pufferpanel/servers/bd502203/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 887, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/lib/pufferpanel/servers/bd502203/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 880, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'scorepost' raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'initial_data' where it is not associated with a value
````

The parts of the code that should be relevant

```py
...
def int_to_santised_int(value: int) -> int:
    if value == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        mods_to_check = [1024, 512, 256, 64, 16, 8, 2] # FL, NC, HT, DT, HR, HD, EZ
        combined_value = 0
        for mod in mods_to_check:
            if value & mod:
                combined_value |= mod
        return combined_value

def extract_initial_data(initial_data):
    try:
        beatmap_id, rank, score_max, n300, n100, n50, nmiss, perfect, int_mods, score_id = (
            initial_data[0]["beatmap_id"], 
            initial_data[0]["rank"],
            int(initial_data[0]["maxcombo"]), 
            int(initial_data[0]["count300"]), 
            int(initial_data[0]["count100"]), 
            int(initial_data[0]["count50"]), 
            int(initial_data[0]["countmiss"]), 
            initial_data[0]["perfect"], 
            int_to_santised_int(int(initial_data[0]["enabled_mods"])),
            initial_data[0]["score_id"]
        )
    except IndexError as e:
        print(f"an exception occurred: '{e}'; that user probably doesn't have any data available.")
        raise
    return beatmap_id, rank, score_max, n300, n100, n50, nmiss, perfect, int_mods, score_id

...

def scorepost(username : str, link : bool, mode : str):
 # make a request to the osu! API to retrieve the user's most recent play
    if link == False:
        try:
            print(f"making initial score request for {username}...")
            inital_response_user = requests.get(f"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user_recent?k={osu_api_key}&u={username}&m={gamemode}&limit=1")
            print(inital_response_user)
        except:
            return "No plays done by that player recently"
        else:
            # parse the response as JSON
            initial_data = inital_response_user.json()

    beatmap_id, rank, score_max, n300, n100, n50, nmiss, perfect, int_mods, score_id = extract_initial_data(initial_data)
```

I've tried moving the line of the error inside of the if and inside of the else in the try except part and making `initial_data` a global variable before adding a value in `initial_data = inital_response_user.json()` and before the `if link == False:`

Comment: Inside of the else-block of the "try" should actually work (or at least produce a different error). Even inside of the if-block (at the same position) should do.

Comment: Isn't `scorepost()` missing a `return` statement in the non-error case?

Comment: This error will happen when `link == True`. Then you skip the `try` code, so it never sets `initial_data`.

Comment: The return in `scorepost()` is wayy at the bottom. And `link == True` only happens when I run a different command in another part of the code, but I ommited it on the code.

Comment: If I put the else block, it produces the same error, but when I try to use one of the variables